# Reactjs - Override href in anchor with onClick

Tags: onclick, anchor

```
<a onClick={this.props.clickFunction.bind(this, type, route)} href='#'>LinkText</a>
```

The only way I can get the `onClick` to work, is to add `#` to the `href`.
But this means that `#` appears in the browser status bar and it's not much use to screen readers.

```
<a onClick={this.props.clickFunction.bind(this, type, route)} href='{route}'>LinkText</a>
```

If I use `{route}` in the `href`, I get the url in the status bar, but the `clickFunction` is not getting the `route` passed to it. So the onClick is getting overrode by the `href`

Is there anyway to get the second scenario to work and have the `clickFunction` perform its function and determine the routing rather than the `href`?

`event.preventDefault()` does not work in this case as it is forcing the page to refresh completely.